# Chebyshev's Prime Number theorem proof of π(2n) ≤ $\frac{6n}{\log_2 n}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to show that for any positive integer $n$, the number of prime numbers not exceeding $2n$ is bounded above by $\frac{6n}{\log_2n}$. That is, $\pi(2n) \leq \frac{6n}{\log_2n}$. All I have to start with is that $\pi(2n) - \pi(n) \lt \frac{2n}{\log_2n}$. I am not sure how to get rid of the $\pi(n)$ term and express the inequality in terms of just $\pi(2n)$.

Comment: Induction on $n$? Rewrite as $\pi(2n)<\frac{2n}{\log_2 n}+\pi(n)$. Assume the desired inequality is true for all $m<n$. Now consider the cases where $n$ is odd and the case where $n$ is even separately.

Comment: I think I can prove it for the even case. It can be shown by hand that $\pi(2n)\leq \frac{6n}{\log_2n}$ for $1\lt n\lt 16$. Then, for $n \geq 16$, $$\pi(n)+\frac{2n}{\log_2n}\leq \frac{3n}{log_2\frac{n}{2}}+\frac{2n}{\log_2n}\leq \frac{6n}{\log_2n}$$. This follows because $\frac{n}{2}$ is a positive integer strictly less than $n$. So by the induction hypothesis, $\pi(2n)\leq \frac{6n}{\log_2n}$. I am having trouble proving the same for the case when n is odd though.

Comment: If $n$ is odd and $n\ge 3$, simply replace $n$ by $n+1$, which is even. We find $\pi(2n)< \pi(n+1)+\frac{2n}{\log_2n}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: From the induction hypothesis it follows that
$$\pi(2n)\lt \frac{3n+3}{\log_2(n+1)-1}+\frac{2n}{\log_2n}$$
Would it be sufficient to show that the limit of the quotient of this function and $\frac{6n}{\log_2n}$ is bounded by 1 as n goes to infinity, or is that no longer an inductive proof?